# How can I query for all the Comments posted by a Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In other words, for any given Facebook user, how can I retrieve all the public comments against any number of URLs (which are not known at the time of the query)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't query comments by user id alone. As you can see from the [FQL Comment](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) table, `fromid` (ie the user submitting a comment) is not indexable. To query Comments you would require atleast one of the following which could be used in conjunction with `fromid`:

> **xid**
> The external ID of the fb:comments being queried. You can specify more than one XID.
>
> **object_id**
> The object_id of an object on Facebook. This can be a video, note, link, photo, or photo album. Note that for photos and albums, the object_id must be queried from the photo and album FQL tables. Note that in the photo and album tables, object_id is a different field from pid and aid. You must specify either an xid or an object_id.
>
> **post_id**
> The ID of the post in the stream.